# Heroku can't find assets outside of the default pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

In Rails the typical pipeline for assets is:

```
images/*
javascripts/*
stylesheets/*
```

I want to add this folder:

```
images/reports_2019/*
```

---

### Two ways that work locally but not on Heroku

Locally, I can either access an asset like this:

```
  = image_tag('reports_2019/zurich_02_pizza')
```

OR I can add this to the `assets.rb` file:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

And then access the asset like normal:

```
  = image_tag('zurich_02_pizza')
```

But these methods *doesn't* work on Heroku :(

I'm getting errors like this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "reports_2019/zurich_02_pizza" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
```

Can anyone help me out, and explain why heroku can't find what my local machine can?

Answer (score 0):

You need the file extension for Heroku to recognise asset paths.

```
= image_tag('reports_2019/zurich_02_pizza.png')
```

or

```
= image_tag('reports_2019/zurich_02_pizza.jpg')
```